# You can't use `the character 0' after \the

Tags: tikz-pgf

I tried to draw the following picture usin Tikz, but got the error message in the title of this issue.

[image]

This is the code I am using. Observe that the error message comes when I try to insert the node `$v_0$`. Can anyone tell me whats going wrong here?

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\def\fin{3} %... end of the slope
\def\bot{-2} %... height of the slope
\def\mp{2} %... x-coordinate of final moto's position
%... environment
\draw[gray!50,fill=gray!50,very thick]
    (-2,0)--
        (0,0)--
        (\fin,\bot)--
        (\fin+1,\bot)--
        (\fin+1,\bot-0.2)--
        (-2,\bot-0.2)--cycle
    ;

%-> DEFINE THE MOTO PICTURE (#1=size, #2=location, #3=rotation)
\def\moto#1#2#3{
    \def\wd{#1} %... wheel axis distance and moto height
    \def\wr{#1/4} %... wheel radius
    \def\pos{#2++(0,\wr)} %... position of the very bottom point of the wheel

    %... wheels
    \draw[gray!50,very thick]
        \pos circle(\wr)
        {\pos+({#3}:\wd)} circle(\wr)
        ;
    %... chassis
    \draw[gray!50,fill=gray!50]
        {\pos+({#3+120}:{6*\wr/5})} arc({120+#3}:{#3}:{6*\wr/5})--++
            ({#3}:{\wd-12*\wr/5}) arc({#3+180}:{#3+60}:{6*\wr/5})--++
                ({#3+90}:{\wr/5}) arc({#3+60}:{#3+90}:{9*\wr/5})--++
            ({#3+120}:{\wr})--++
            ({#3+210}:{2*\wr})--++
            ({#3+180}:{3*\wr})
        ;
    %... motorcyclist
    \draw[gray!50,line width={4*\wd}]
        {\pos+({#3+60}:{6*\wr/5})}--++
            ({#3+60}:{3*\wr})
        {\pos++({#3+60}:{4*\wr})} circle({2*\wr/3})
        {\pos++({#3+60}:{3*\wr})}--++
            ({#3-10}:{2*\wr})
        ;
    %... velocity vector
    %\draw[->,gray!50,very thick]
    %    {\pos++({#3}:{\wd})++({#3+90}:{\wr})}--++
    %        ({#3}:{\wd})% node[above]{$v_0$}
    %    ;
}
%... the sizes
\draw[<->,thick,white]
    (0,0)--
        (0,\mp*\bot/\fin) node[midway,fill=gray!50]{$h$}
    ;
\draw[<->,thick,white]
    (0,\mp*\bot/\fin-0.1)--
        (\mp,\mp*\bot/\fin-0.1) node[midway,fill=gray!50]{$x$}
    ;
\draw[gray!50,dashed,thick]
    (-0.5,0.25)--
        (0,0.25) to[out=0,in=100]
        (\mp+0.25,{(\mp+0.25)*\bot/\fin})
    ;

\moto{0.5}{(-1.5,0)}{0}
    \draw[->,gray!50,very thick]
        (-1,0.3)--
            (-0.5,0.3)% node[above]{$v_0$}
        ;
    \draw[gray!50]
        (-0.5,0.3) node[above]{$v_0$}
        ;
\moto{0.5}{(\mp,\mp*\bot/\fin)}{atan(\bot/\fin)}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Comment: Don't redefine `\wd`.  `\wd` is a TeX (very used) primitive. Call it `\wad` or some other name.

Comment: Thank you very much, @PhelypeOleinik! Can you please post as an aswer so I can mark it?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The problem is that you redefined TeX's `\wd` primitive, which gets the width of a box. Try the example below with the `\def\wd{0.5}` (which is what your code does when you call `\moto{0.5}`) uncommented:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\newbox\tempbox
\setbox\tempbox\hbox{Don't \emph{ever} redefine \TeX's internals.}

% \def\wd{0.5}
The width of the following warning is: \the\wd\tempbox

\box\tempbox

\end{document}
```

Once you change `\wd` by something that is not used by TeX then it will work.

This is one of the main reasons that LaTeX's `\newcommand` and its successors are recommended for end users and raise an error if a command is already defined: error messages get a *whole* lot more interesting if you redefine something you shouldn't.

Comment: A long term target for LaTeX3 is to express all internal functions in terms of aliases of the primitives, so redefining a primitive will not be a problem. Of course, *all* packages should follow suit, which is the big issue.